# Removing logic from view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index view that iterates through a list of products with specific state_taxonomies.  I was able to get the logic to work with a query request within the view, but I'm assuming `<% Product.where(id: st.product_id).each do |tax| %>` logic should not display within a view?

1. Where should I put this logic?
2. How should I create this method?  I've tried a few routes but failed.

**Products index view user Bootstrap nav-pills:**

```
<div>
  <% @state_taxonomies.each do |st| %>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= st.id %>">
      <% Product.where(id: st.product_id).each do |tax| %>
        <%= link_to tax.title, tax %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Products Controller:**

```
def index
  @products = Product.all.page params[:page]
  @state_taxonomies = StateTaxonomy.all 
end
```

Note: products has_many :state_taxonomies and state_taxonomy belongs_to :product.

Comment: Your logic should be exactly in Products controller. Instead of **@products = Porduct..all.page params[:page]** you should select on the products you need in your view, instead of doing this at view level.

Comment: I edited you question because you had a `</div>` without a corresponding `<div>`.

Comment: When possible, give us a position if the answers helped you. If possible, even choose a favorite answer. This helps those who helped you and helps this site by improving the quality of the answers.

Comment: I haven't found an answer yet.  I will let you know when I do

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a lot of queries, first in your controller `Product.all` (you don't seem to use the result) and `StateTaxonomy.all`. But the worse is in your view, you do a `Product.where(id: st.product_id)` for each `@state_taxonomies`.

You should research the n+1 problem and [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Also, never do a query in a view, that goes in the controller.

All you need is to include the products when you query for StateTaxonomy in your controller :

```
@state_taxonomies = StateTaxonomy.all.includes(:product)
```

Then in your view :

```
<% @state_taxonomies.each do |st| %>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= st.id %>">
    <% st.products.each do |tax| %>
      <%= link_to tax.title, tax %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit :
I just realized the view can't work this way. In your models, a state_taxonomy belongs to a product, so it can only have one product. I don't know if that is what you want or if it's an error.

You can either only show one product per state_taxonomy :

```
<% @state_taxonomies.each do |st| %>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= st.id %>">
    <%= link_to st.product.title, st.product %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

or change the relation between the two models, maybe you want `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: Great solution. Better than mine.

Comment: With your suggestion, I am getting these results 'uninitialized constant StateTaxonomy::Products`

Comment: @jgrant I wrote that a little too fast, I edited the controller line.

Comment: I am seeing the same result

Comment: Sorry, the includes needs to be singular : `includes(:product)` since your state_taxonomy belongs to product.

Comment: @jgrant You should probably post your models.

Answer (score 0):

Your Products controller should be something like:

```
def index
  @state_taxonomies = StateTaxonomy.all
  @products = Hash.new
  @state_taxonomies.each |st| do 
    @products[st.id] == Product.where(id: st.product_id)
  end
end
```

This would store in @products all the required in your view and you could write only:

```
<% @state_taxonomies.each do |st| %>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="<%= st.id %>">
    <% @products[st.id].each do |tax| %>
      <%= link_to tax.title, tax %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```